# Add Dynamic button in android

Tags: android, button

I have a Linear Layout

and I want to add to this Linear Layout a button (from 3 Buttons) Dynamic in Run Time Depending on an integer value that returns from a function

I know how to add a view to a Layout using `AddView` , and how to remove views form layout using `removeView`  ...

but my question is how to check if the view Exists in the layout before call the method `reomveView`

Comment: how is removeView triggered?

Comment: i have a method that return a value , depending on this value I add the proper button, so if another button is in the layout , I want to remove it before add the proper button

Comment: Any certain `Button` or will it be the only `Button` in that `ViewGroup`?

Comment: Why not just hide the view instead of removing it?

Comment: I want to remove it to keep the Design of Layout is good

Comment: you can create 3 buttons overlapping at the same place.. then just set some of the buttons visibility to view.gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you create your buttons beforehand and just set the visibility to `View.GONE`

when you trigger some event you can set other buttons visibility to true while the others are false..

this will work with no problems and you dont have to add them dynamically.. it will just "seem" dynamic :)

You can do that with this code:

```
button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Given the buttons are "`button1`" and "`button2`"

`View.GONE` will "remove" the view from the screen, however it is still "there" it just doesn't appear for the user, and it doesn't take up any space

`View.INVISIBLE` will "remove" the view from the screen, how ever the space it took up is still used by it.

`View.VISIBLE` will show the view as it would usually.

Comment: No problem, it was part of my answer so yeah xD.

Comment: Added a little more info for you :)

Comment: @FrancisFuerte if I use the SetVisibalty(View.GONE) for a GONE view is there any problem ???

Comment: Its `setVisibility` FYI, and it should function as any normal view, the ui just visibly doesn't change if you do changes to the view.